# Traefik docker default domain configuration

Tags: docker, traefik

I used this configuration from traefik v1.

https://docs.traefik.io/v1.0/toml/#docker-backend

What is its equivalent in traefik v2 ?

I'm using this configuration

```
[entryPoints]
  [entryPoints.web]
    address = ":80"

  [entryPoints.web-secure]
    address = ":443"

    [providers.docker]
      endpoint = "unix:///var/run/docker.sock"
      exposedByDefault = true
      watch = true
      useBindPortIP = true
      # if I add domain here traefik service refuses to run.
    [api]
      dashboard = true
      insecure = true
```

Comment: Have you tried to read the migration guide? https://docs.traefik.io/v2.0/migration/v1-to-v2/ - start there then post a more specific quesion.